# TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a user in Firebase and I get the following error: `TypeError: Can not read property 'uid' of undefined`.

In other words, if you create the user but do not write the document.

```
interface User {
uid: string;
email: string;
photoURL?: string;
displayName?: string;
favoriteColor?: string;
fechaRegistro?: string;
}

emailSignUp(email: string, password: string, displayName: string ) {
this._displayName = displayName;

return this.afAuth.auth
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(credential => {
    this.pushUserDataEmail(credential.user);
    console.log('Usuario creado')
    this.router.navigate(['/userProfile'])
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.handleError(error)
  });
}

private pushUserDataEmail( user: User ) {
const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
const data: User = {
  uid: user.uid,
  email: user.email,
  displayName: this._displayName
};
userRef.set(data, {merge: true});
```

}

However when I try this same code from another application it works normal, that is, it creates the user and then writes the document.